# Copy folders from server to client created between specific time stamps?

Tags: windows, batch, date-modified

I want to create a batch file that will delete the folders at my specified destination, then copy all folders modified after 7AM yesterday from my source; this is because I want to be able to run this daily, at 7AM.

The operating system I'm intending to use is Windows Server 2003.

Thus, basically I want to be able to replace the current contents of a folder, with all changed files from the last 24 hours.

Comment: I cannot see an easy way (ie: without extra tools - eg: rsync or at least using vbscript). XCOPY /D only does it on a day basis.

Comment: That is what the problem is!!!!!!

Comment: I understand. It's possible, but tedious. You can use various batch functions and tricks to extract file details and compare them. I'll add an answer in an hour or two...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP added a whole lot of functionality to batch parameters and commands but they aren't all that easy to use. Be very careful with quoting as files can contain spaces. I've kept the quotes around filenames as it's more useful that way.

The place to start with batch generally is "help" (in a CMD shell naturally). Then "cmd /?", "set /?", "for /?" and also the [Microsoft batch website](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true). This is what I've done - it's not complete but will print out files changed since yesterday at 7am. I can add further bits if you want. I'll keep this myself as I sometimes want to know what files I've changed today!

(Edited: Yesterday is harder than just subtracting one from the day!...)

```
@echo off

setlocal

rem Start at current directory. Customise as you wish.

set my_root=.

rem First get yesterday at 7am.
rem The format of %DATE% depends on locale so this is a
rem hack using a tmp file in VBScript...
rem Note the use of the caret, which is the batch escape character

echo yday = DateAdd("d", -1, Date) > "%temp%\tmp$$$.vbs"
echo Wscript.Echo DatePart("yyyy",yday) ^& Right("0" ^& DatePart("m",yday), 2) ^& Right("0" ^& DatePart("d",yday), 2) >> "%temp%\tmp$$$.vbs"

for /F %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\tmp$$$.vbs"') do set after_ymd=%%a

if exist "%temp%\tmp$$$.vbs" del "%temp%\tmp$$$.vbs"

set after_time=0700

echo Files after: %after_ymd% %after_time%

for /R %my_root% %%f in (*.*) do call :checkdate "%%f" "%%~tf"

goto :EOF


:checkdate

set fname=%1
set fdate=%2

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=./-: " %%a in (%fdate%) do (
    set f_d=%%a
    set f_m=%%b
    set f_y=%%c
    set f_hr=%%d
    set f_mn=%%e
)

if %f_y%%f_m%%f_d% LSS %after_ymd% goto :EOF

if %f_y%%f_m%%f_d% EQU %after_ymd% if %f_hr%%f_mn% LSS %after_time% goto :EOF

REM Copy your file here...

echo Newer: %fname%

goto :EOF
```

Note that echoing VBScript in a batch file is prone to error and is messy. The preferred method is to create a fixed vbs file that can be called at will. Another way is to append the vbscript to the end of the batch file, mark each line with a tag, make sure to preceed the script with goto :EOF and use findstr on the script itself to grep the strings out (yes, it's nasty):

```
echo off & setlocal enableextensions
rem Build a script:
findstr "'VBS" "%~f0" | findstr /v "findstr" > %TEMP%\tmp$$$.vbs

....

goto :EOF
'
'VBS
DateAdd("d", -1, Date) 'VBS
Wscript.Echo DatePart("yyyy",yday) & Right("0" & DatePart("m",yday), 2) & Right("0" & DatePart("d",yday), 2) 'VBS
```

Yes. It's not pleasant.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Carveone.... this is very much helpful... but can u please clarify, what will happen on the first day any month!!!

Comment: Oh! Good catch! As you can see I did it for "today", remembered you wanted "yesterday" and quickly threw in the two lines to subtract one. I didn't even use another variable name. That's what I get for not testing edge cases. You're right - the code is incorrect as it stands, also for dates like 20130102 which turn into 2013011. Oh dear.

Comment: I suppose it's too late to ask can one use VBScript. It's installed on everything by default :-) "yesterday" turns out to be annoying to calculate given leap years etc.

Comment: Yeah!!! that's what even I faced. So to achieve my desired I output.. I have merged codes from two different sources i.e. yours and other written by "Rob van der Woude" for finding yesterdays date. And my problem is solved.  Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome. I redid the code anyway using a tmp file in vbscript, because the existing code was totally wrong and I had to really! It was harder to do than I thought, mostly because of leading zeros (thanks to: http://sogeeky.blogspot.ie/2006/08/vbscript-add-leading-zero-to-date.html) and oddity of batch file escaping (^)

Comment: Oh and I edited the answer which appears to lose me the "accepted answer" tick thing. Darn...

Comment: Does that make any difference if u loose that "accepted answer" thing.... anyways I thank you for all the effort you invested in solving the problem!! THANKS..!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend you install PowerShell on... whatever device you run this from, and you might be happy with the results.

```
# Define the folder that you want to copy FROM
$SourceFolder = "D:\test"

# Define the folder that you want to copy FROM, AND DELETE CONTENTS FROM BEFORE DOING SO
$DestinationFolder = "D:\testTarget"

# Make any changes to what criteria you want for the copying
$CopyingCriteria = $( Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) } )

If ( $CopyingCriteria ) {
    # Delete the items of the folder
    Get-ChildItem $DestinationFolder | Remove-Item -Force

    # Copy the files that have changed using criteria already defined
    $CopyingCriteria | Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationFolder -Force

}
```

Save it as a **as-you-want.ps1**, make sure you've set your execution policy to Unrestricted (or sign the above and change it to AllSigned) and run!

Comment: Thanks Thor for the suggestion, but I can't install anything on client. Restricted access.